# How can i save state my button after refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this sample:

[link](https://jsfiddle.net/sr099aa8/)

**CODE HTML:**

```
<div class="square">
</div>
```

**CODE CSS:**

```
.square{
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    background:green;
}

.fa-square{
    background:red;
     width:20px;
    height:20px;
}
```

**CODE JS:**

```
$("div").click(function(){

                      if ( $( this ).hasClass( "fa-square" ) ) {
                           $( this ).removeClass('fa-square').addClass('square');
                      }else{
                             $('.square').removeClass('square').addClass('fa-square');
                      }
            });
```

What I want to do is simply believe ...
I want to save the state after refresh the page button

For example ... if the button is green and is ... then remain green refresh after refresh
If the button is red, red remain after refresh.

How can you do that?
Anyone can show me a simple example?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to pass the last known state of your button to server side else the button state will be lost on the page refresh.

Comment: ok,and how can i do that?:) I need an short example

Comment: Try `cookie` / `localStorage`.

Comment: Or try with a hash/querystring.

Answer (score 0):

You can set cookies and read them at the beginning of the content to check if a state is set like this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sr099aa8/1/)

```
function readCookie(name) {
return (name = new RegExp('(?:^|;\\s*)' + ('' + name).replace(/[-[\]{} ()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, '\\$&') + '=([^;]*)').exec(document.cookie)) && name[1];
}
if(readCookie('state') == "fa-square"){
$('div').addClass('fa-square');
}else if(readCookie('state') == "square"){
$('div').addClass('square');
}
$("div").click(function () {
if ($(this).hasClass("fa-square")) {
    $(this).removeClass('fa-square').addClass('square');
    document.cookie= "state=square";
} else {
    $('.square').removeClass('square').addClass('fa-square');
    document.cookie= "state=fa-square";
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('class');
if(retrievedObject){
    $('div').addClass(retrievedObject)
}

console.log('class ', (retrievedObject));
$("div").click(function () {

    if ($(this).hasClass("fa-square")) {
        $(this).removeClass('fa-square').addClass('square');
        localStorage.setItem('class', 'square');
    } else {
        $('.square').removeClass('square').addClass('fa-square');
        localStorage.setItem('class', 'fa-square');
    }



});
```

This one utilizes the localstorage to store the value of class then on onload give the stored class to the div

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/sr099aa8/7/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this example using `localStorage`

```js
$(function() {
  var cls = 'state'; //key name for local storage
  var sqr = $('.square');
  sqr.addClass(localStorage.getItem(cls)); //restore state on page load
  sqr.on('click', function() {
    sqr.toggleClass('fa-square'); //shorthand for add/remove class
    localStorage.setItem(cls, this.className); //preserve current state on every click
  });
});
```

```css
.square {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: green;
}
.fa-square {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="square"></div>
```